# Double-click headphone button to change track function

Tags: headphones, remote-control, spotify

When listening to music on iTunes on my MacBook Air running OS 10.9, I am able to double-click the center headphone button to change track.

I am wondering if it is possible to replicate this behavior to when I am listening to music in e. g. Spotify.

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes, but with no success unfortunately. If a single-click the center button my latest played song on Itunes starts playing even though I have the Spotify window open.

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected in Spotify v1.0.65.320 for all interested.